# Limiting Maximum selection in BOXI Multivalued parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I have a BOXI report that uses a multi-valued parameter. My requirement is to limit the selection of values to 20 (maximum input by users can not be more than 20).

Can someone please suggest a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using one of SAP's product (e.g. Enterprise, Crystal Reports Server) to generate the report or do you have a custom framework?

Comment: I'm using crystal report XI to generate report. Within the report I've created a parameter with "Allow multiple values" to True.

Comment: Crystal Reports doesn't have a way to limit parameter usage in this manner.